# Is it possible to use custom icon for Xcode file template?

Tags: xcode

In our project we generate multiple swift files when using the file xctemplate configuration. However, with this configuration, there is no icon displayed in Xcode when generating the files (see attached image). We did try to add two images to the template folder: TemplateIcon-png and TemplateIcon@96.png which yielded no success. Is it possible to use a custom icon for file templates in Xcode?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this, but you should be able to create an `.icns` icon package named `TemplateIcon.icns`. This should contain your template image(s) to be displayed in the new project picker.

I suspect your issue was trying to use the PNG assets directly.

See the [Base Acceptance Testing Bundle](https://github.com/paulstringer/OCSlimProjectXcodeTemplates/tree/master/Xcode%20Templates/Base%20Acceptance%20Testing%20Bundle.xctemplate) for an example. It is part of the [OCSlimProjectXcodeTemplates](https://github.com/paulstringer/OCSlimProjectXcodeTemplates) repository.